# How to deploy to AWS with circleci 2.0?

Tags: amazon-web-services, circleci, circleci-2.0

I have `config.yaml` I try upload code to AWS. On first version it's works fine, but now it's doesn't work. How can I fix it? I added `deploy` section and wrote sh commands

```
version: 2
    jobs:
      build:
        working_directory: ~/myProject
        parallelism: 1
        shell: /bin/bash --login
        environment:
          CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS: /tmp/circleci-artifacts
          CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS: /tmp/circleci-test-results
        docker:
        - image: circleci/build-image:ubuntu-14.04-XXL-upstart-1189-5614f37
          command: /sbin/init
        steps:
        - checkout
        - run: mkdir -p $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS
        - run:
            working_directory: ~/myProject
            command: nvm install 8.9.1 && nvm alias default 8.9.1
        - restore_cache:
            keys:
            - v1-dep-{{ .Branch }}-
            - v1-dep-master-
            - v1-dep-
        - run: sudo sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe restricted multiverse"
        - run: sudo apt update
        - run: sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
        - run: sudo easy_install --upgrade six
        - run: sudo pip install --upgrade urllib3==1.21.1
        - run: sudo pip install --upgrade pip
        - run: sudo pip install --upgrade blessed
        - run: sudo pip install awsebcli==3.12.3 --ignore-installed six pyyaml
        - run: rm -rf /home/ubuntu/.aws
        - run: if [ -z "${NODE_ENV:-}" ]; then export NODE_ENV=test; fi
        - run: export PATH="~/myProject/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
        - run: npm install
        - save_cache:
            key: v1-dep-{{ .Branch }}-{{ epoch }}
            paths:
            - vendor/bundle
            - ~/virtualenvs
            - ~/.m2
            - ~/.ivy2
            - ~/.bundle
            - ~/.go_workspace
            - ~/.gradle
            - ~/.cache/bower
            - ./node_modules
        - run: npm test
        - store_test_results:
            path: /tmp/circleci-test-results
        - store_artifacts:
            path: /tmp/circleci-artifacts
        - store_artifacts:
            path: /tmp/circleci-test-results
    deploy:
        name: deploy to AWS
        production:
            branch: production
            commands:
                - bash ./deploy_prod.sh
                - eb deploy stmi-production
        staging:
            branch: master
            commands:
                - bash ./deploy_staging.sh
                - eb deploy stmi-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
machine: true
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: create workspace
          command: mkdir -p /tmp/workspace
      - run:
          name: Install awsebcli package
          command: |
            sudo apt-get -y -qq update
            sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential
            sudo pip install --upgrade awsebcli
            eb --version
      - run:
          name: installing dependencies
          command: |
            npm  install 
      - run:
          name: deploy 
          command: |
           bash deploy.sh
      - run:
          name: Removing aws config
          command: |
            rm -rf /home/circleci/.aws
      - run: ls /tmp/workspace
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: /tmp/workspace
          paths:
            - status.txt`
```

And this is my deploy.sh

```
 mkdir /home/circleci/.aws
 touch /home/circleci/.aws/config
 chmod 600 /home/circleci/.aws/config
 echo "[profile user]" > /home/circleci/.aws/config
 echo "aws_access_key_id=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" >> /home/circleci/.aws/config
 echo "aws_secret_access_key=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" >> 
 /home/circleci/.aws/config

  eb deploy $BEANSTALK_ENVIRONMENT --profile user --region 
  $BEANSTALK_PRODUCTION_AWS_REGION &&
  echo 'Deployment Succeed' >> /tmp/workspace/beanstalk-deploy- 
  status.txt
```